# How to select only some classes of an element

Tags: jquery, filter, selection

I have a table header cell, which has both formatting and functional classes, like so:

```
 <th class="persistent optional some-other-classes">
```

I want to copy *persistent* and *optional* to all following table cells but having a hard time with selecting the appropriate classes

I'm trying this, but it doesn't get me anywhere...

```
 $('th, TH').filter( '.persistent, .optional')
```

Is there a way to grab only these two classes without referencing *some-other-class* by name?

Thanks for help!

**EDIT: more info**
Items will have more than 3 classes. I only want to copy/paste the persistent and optional classes, which handle table appearance, and leave the formatting classes

It should be something like:

```
 $('th, TH').attr(class).filter( '.persistent, .optional' )
```

which doesn't work of course.

Comment: Do you mean items that have *both* classes, excluding items that only have one of them?

Comment: I need to copy **persistent** and **optional** to all table cells below. so my selection would have to be "select all classes of th which match persistent and optional". Hope that was clear enough.

Comment: @frequent to be clear, you want to end up with elements with **only** the 'optional' (if present) and 'persistent' (if present) classes. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of meddling, this is my solution that works:

```
    var classes = "",

    allClasses = th.attr("class").split(/\s+/);

    for (var j = 0; j < allClasses.length; j++) {
          if (allClasses[j] === 'persistent' || allClasses[j] === 'optional' ) {
             classes = classes+" "+allClasses[j]
             }
    }

    console.log(classes)  
    // returns "persistent optional" or "persistent" or "optional"
    // leaves away all other classes
```

If there is an easier way to filter out these two classes, I would be happy to give the answer to someone.

THANKS for all your efforts and sorry for not telling exactly what I needed.

Comment: I've updated my answer, based on what I think your requirements are, which is *hopefully* simpler than the above.

Answer (score 1):

The following will match `th` elements that have either class:

```
$('th.persistent, th.optional');
```

or to match `th` elements that have both:

```
$('th.persistent.optional');
```

Or, to get elements that have a class of only persistent *or* only optional *or* only both:

```
$('th.persistent, th.optional').filter(function() {
  var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
  return classes.length == 1 || (classes.length == 2 && $(this).is('.persistent.optional');
};
```

**Update**

Okay, I think I understand your requirement now - if a table header is `.optional` all `td` elements in the column should also have the `.optional` class, similarly for `.persistent`:

```
$('th.persistent, th.optional').each(function() {
  var th = $(this);
  var col = th.parent().children().index(th);
  th.closest('table').find('td').each(function() {
    var td = $(this);
    if (td.parent().children().index(td) === col) {
      if (th.is('.persistent')) td.addClass('persistent');
      if (th.is('.optional')) td.addClass('optional');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select only elements with class persistent and optional, try this:

```
$('th[class="persistent optional"], th[class="optional persistent"]')
```

It won't work it there will be additional spaces. If you need to handle such cases pass function to the filter:

```
$('th').filter(function(){ 
    return this.className.match(/^\s*(persistent\s+optional|optional\s+persistent)\s*$/);
})
```

Comment: I think my questions wasn't precise enough. I need to come up with a selection containing class name "persistent" and "optional" but not any other class.

Answer (score 0):

For intersection you need `filter('.persistent.optional')`, no space no commas.

Comment: see my comment above. I need to get a selection that contains only persisten and optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to assign class names to a set of previously matched elements:

```
$("th").addClass("persistent optional")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle to select items that contains only specified classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/hYgqS/

here is the sample html

```
<div class="a1 a2 b">
1
</div>
<div class="a1 a2">
2
</div>
```

here is the JS code

```
$('div.a1.a2').filter(function(){
return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').length ==2
}).text("this one");
```